# Finding inverse of matrix with trig functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$\begin{bmatrix} \cos(30^\circ) & 0 \\ \sin(30^\circ) & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

I am fine with finding the inverse of a standard $2 \times 2$ matrix but I am struggling to find the inverse of this one as it contains trig functions. I understand that the trig identity is $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x=1$ and I tried to apply this but was getting strange results.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\sin(30^{\circ})$ and $\cos(30^{\circ})$ are just numbers.  Do you know what they are?  If you replace the trig functions with the numbers you know they are, then you have a "standard $2\times 2$ matrix."

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{bmatrix} \cos(30^\circ) & 0 \\ \sin(30^\circ) & 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{3}/2 & 0 \\ 1/2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: Use the fact that $\cos (30^{\circ}) = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, and $\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{ad-bc}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} d & - b \\ -c & a \end{pmatrix}$